# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

Good day! Error occurs by using Repository and UnitOfWork pattern (I am trying to add object to the database). By calling DatabaseContext without patterns is all okay.

There is Unit Of Work :

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private IRepository<User> _userRepository;

    private readonly DatabaseContext context;
    public UnitOfWork(DatabaseContext _context)
    {
        context = _context;
    }

    public IRepository<User> UserRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_userRepository == null)
            {
                _userRepository = new Repository<User>(context);
            }

            return _userRepository;
        }
    }

    async Task<int> IUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync() => await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    private bool disposed = false;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

}

There is a method of adding to the database (Repository) :

```
public async Task InsertAsync(TEntity entity)
{
    await dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
}
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."

Error occurs on the line of saving changes by disposing (code of Dispose is upper)

```
await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The simple method of saving :

```
async Task<int> IUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync() => await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Hi, could you please not post images but post the code and any error messages directly? It is now unreadable.

Comment: Okay i will edit it

Comment: I was trying to make the right structure of the project, will it not provide a pattern to the Repository? There is no need in it?

Comment: Are you running some tasks in parallel by any chance?

Comment: No parallel tasks, only one post request trying to do

Comment: An “already open DataReader“ usually means that you are currently trying to make a query to the database, while you are still looking at the results from _another_ query. For example, when you loop over an IEnumerable of a query/DbSet and you want to make queries within the loop body. You should materialize your query results early (e.g. using `ToListAsync`) so that you can disconnect from the reader, or use a _separate_ database connection, using a separate DbContext (which is kind of difficult to do when you add another abstraction layer with your UnitOfWork).

Comment: replace await dbSet.AddAsync(entity); with  dbSet.Add(entity);

Comment: I tried to replace await dbSet.AddAsync(entity); with dbSet.Add(entity); It is no changing. Then i tried to replace async SaveChanges to sync func and it works! Thanks for helping!